# how to save selection meta data in user profile on frontend

Tags: php, select

Hi can anyone help me to save the post title selected in this select box? I would like to let people select posts out of a dropdown select box and save the value to their profile.

Help is very appreciated!

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'product_selection_field', 5 );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'product_selection_field', 5 );
function product_selection_field( $user ) {
$args     = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'product_tag' => 'partner' );
$products = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $products as $page ) {
            if ( strtolower($product_name) == $page ) {
                $role_option .= "<option value='".strtolower($page->post_title)."' selected='selected'>";
                $currentrole = strtolower($role_name);
            } else {
                $product_option .= "<option value='".strtolower($page->post_title)."'>";
            }

            $product_option .= $page->post_title;
            $product_option .= "</option>";

}
?>
<div class="form-group full-width">
<label for="club_choice"><?php _e("Select your club"); ?></label>
    <select name="club_choice" id="club_choice" class="input"> 
    <?php 
    echo $product_option;
    ?>
    </select>
</div>
<?php 
}

 // then I save the field
 add_action('user_register','adding_extra_reg_fields');
 function adding_extra_reg_fields($user_id) {
if ( !empty( $_POST['club_choice'] ) )
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'club_choice', $_POST['club_choice'] );

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahh it turns out it wasn't able to stay selected because I was using the "strtolower" function to remove capital letters. Which in turn caused there to be a mismatch between the selected value and the saved value in the database.

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'product_selection_field', 3 );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'product_selection_field', 3 );

function product_selection_field( $user ) {
if( current_user_can('free') || current_user_can('administrator') ) {
$user_ID = get_current_user_id();
$current_product = get_user_meta( $user_ID, "club_choice", true );
$args     = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'product_tag' => 'partner' );
$products = get_posts( $args );

   foreach ( $products as $page ) {
    $string = $page->post_title;
    $product_option .= "<option value='" . $page->post_title . "' " . selected(     $current_product, $string, false ) . ">";
    $product_option .= $page->post_title;
    $product_option .= "</option>";
}
?>
<div class="form-group full-width">
    <?php
  $user_ID = get_current_user_id();
  $all_meta_for_user = get_user_meta( $user_ID, "club_choice", true );
  echo '<label><strong>Your current club selected is: </label>';
  print_r( $all_meta_for_user );
  echo '</strong><br/>';
?>
</div>
<div class="form-group full-width">
    <label for="club_choice"><?php _e("Select your club"); ?></label>
        <select name="club_choice" id="club_choice" class="input"> 
            <?php 
        echo $product_option;
        ?>
        </select>
</div>
<?php 
}
}


// then I save the field
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'adding_club_reg_fields', 10, 1 );
add_action( 'user_register', 'adding_club_reg_fields', 10, 1 );
function adding_club_reg_fields( $user_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['club_choice'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'club_choice', $_POST['club_choice'] );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below works. I added `personal_options_update` action hook to save user profile.
In `product_selection_field` function you need to get user meta value first.
Besides you can use selected function to add selected attribute to option tag.

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'product_selection_field' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'product_selection_field' );

function product_selection_field( $user ) {
    $product_name = get_user_meta( $user->id, "club_choice", true );
    $args     = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'product_tag' => 'partner' );
    $products = get_posts( $args );

    foreach ( $products as $page ) {
        $product_option .= "<option value='" . strtolower( $page->post_title ) . "' " . selected( $product_name, $page->post_name, false ) . ">";
        $product_option .= $page->post_title;
        $product_option .= "</option>";
    }
?>
<div class="form-group full-width">
    <label for="club_choice"><?php _e("Select your club"); ?></label>
        <select name="club_choice" id="club_choice" class="input"> 
        <?php 
        echo $product_option;
        ?>
        </select>
    </div>
<?php 
}

// then I save the field
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'adding_extra_reg_fields', 10, 1 );
add_action( 'user_register', 'adding_extra_reg_fields', 10, 1 );
function adding_extra_reg_fields( $user_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['club_choice'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'club_choice', $_POST['club_choice'] );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi yes, I see I had the wrong action on this paste.. Actually the value is saving now. I created a dump with  $all_meta_for_user = get_user_meta( );
  print_r( $all_meta_for_user );
Just the value wont stay selected in the dropdown. Which is kind of a problem..